# How to animate TaskBarItemInfo.Overlay Image?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, animation, taskbar

I'm trying to make a spinning syncing icon in the taskbar, but i can't seem to make it work.
**I can make images appear, but no animation.**

According to MSDN it is possible to animate the overlay image of the TaskBarItemInfo.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo.overlay.aspx)

I've tried using storyboards and an animated gif but nothing moves.

Anyone got an idea?

EDIT: storyboard test

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <TransformedBitmap x:Key="TaskbarOverlayImageSync"
                       Source="/Joni_Planner;component/Resources/TabItemIcons/sync4.png">
        <TransformedBitmap.Transform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
        </TransformedBitmap.Transform>
    </TransformedBitmap>
    <Storyboard x:Key="TaskbarOverlayStoryboard"
                RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TaskbarItem"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Overlay.(TransformedBitmap.Transform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                         By="10"
                         To="360"
                         Duration="0:0:1.5"
                         FillBehavior="Stop" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TaskbarItemInfo x:Name="TaskbarItem"/>
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
```

CodeBehind:

```
var taskbarAnimateStoryboard = (Storyboard) FindResource("TaskbarOverlayStoryboard");
TaskbarItem.Overlay = (ImageSource)FindResource("TaskbarOverlayImageSync");
taskbarAnimateStoryboard.Begin();
```

Regards Nautious

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is some antivirus companies ...they are big on animated logos ...

Comment: Question updated. code added.